# how to pass an array instead of path in keras preprocessor

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, keras, python-imaging-library

I want to convert an image that was loaded by cv2 into an specific format with keras preprocessor.
The keras.preprocessing.image.load_image() function takes input as path but i have only the numpy array.
I need help in converting the image into specfic format

The code i want to do is:

```
def convert(img):
    img = load_img(imge, grayscale=True, target_size=(28, 28))
    img = img_to_array(imge)
    img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img / 255.0
    return img
```

Is there any other way to get the above format with numpy array and not with image path.

Comment: So, you have a Numpy array of shape ??? and dtype ??? which is a BGR image loaded by OpenCV ??? and you want to get ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the output by the following method

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

img=cv2.imread('check.jpg')
grey=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized=cv2.resize(grey,(28,28))
np_arr=np.array(resized)
np_arr=np_arr.astype('float32')/255
print(np_arr.size)
```